# Is the phrase "seize the court" etymologically related to the term assizes?

Tags: etymology

From Wikipedia:

> assise < Old French assise ("session, legal action" – past participle of asseoir, "to seat") < Vulgar Latin *assedēre < Latin assidēre ("to sit beside, aside, elsewhere") < ad + sedēre ("to sit").[2] The “courts of assize” were the English equivalent of the still existing French « Cours d'assise ».

Comment: Have you checked the etymology of "seize"?

Comment: Now I have and there's no direct indication however the roots could still be cognates.

Comment: ***seize (v.)***
mid-13c., seisen, "take possession, take possession of" (land, goods, etc.) by force or authority, from Old French seisir "to take possession of, take by force; put in possession of, bestow upon" (Modern French saisir), from Late Latin sacire (8c.), which generally is held to be from Germanic, but the exact source is uncertain.

Comment: What does the phrase "seize the court" mean? I've never heard of it.

Comment: It apparently means  bring an action before it.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244751/what-is-the-meaning-of-seize-in-this-sentence

Comment: I have heard it to mean that the court is actively considering the case [ "When the Supreme Court is seized of the matter, the other courts should await the verdict" ] @AndrewLeach

Comment: Looking to etymologyonline & wiktionary , I see that (1) assize & seize sound similar but are not very much related (2) assize & size are very much related.